# Seeking Help with React Typescript App and Ether.js - Trouble with Tuple Arguments

Tags: typescript, etherjs

I'm currently working on a React Typescript app that involves interacting with contracts on the blockchain using Ether.js. While making progress, I've encountered a hurdle that has me scratching my head.

The issue lies with a particular function that expects a tuple as an argument. However, my research has led me to find examples where arrays are used instead of tuples. I attempted to pass an array as the argument, hoping it would work, but alas, I received an "UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_PRICE" error. Frustrating, isn't it?

To troubleshoot, I manually set a gas limit, but this resulted in the transaction being reverted. Upon investigating etherscan, I made a puzzling discovery. The parameters I passed were interpreted as arrays, while other websites calling the same function seem to handle them differently.

This brings me to seek your valuable insights and ideas. Have any of you encountered a similar situation while working with Ether.js and tuples? How did you resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can offer to help me overcome this roadblock.

Thank you in advance for your support, and let's collaborate to conquer this challenge together!

Comment: Please provide a reproductible code sample. We cannot help you if you do not show us what you have.